# Show PersianCalendar DateTimePicker using Devexpress DateEdit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, calendar, devexpress, persian

I want to insert a Persian DateTimePicker in a page view in mvc3 using devexpress `DateEdit` Component.
I have read and use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344290/Using-a-Persian-calender-in-NET-4) article to set `PersianCalendar` as the current calendar of `CurrentCulture`. It was as easy as set this code in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var persianCulture = new PersianCulture();
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = persianCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = persianCulture;
}
```

everything is OK when i use standard builtin calendar: `<asp: Calendar ...` but it getting odd when i use Devexpress `DateEdit` component.

- month names changed correctly.
- Abbrivated Day Names changed correctly.
- start day of week changed correctly.

but `DaysInMonth` remain as it was in Gregorian calendar. for example in `PersianCalendar` first six months in a year have 31 days and 5 other months have 30 days and the last month have 29 days (and 30 days if it was leap year).
i had very hard time to trace what happened in DevExpress javascript codes and i only find a few things:

- It use javascript `Date` object to manipulate date. (so what is used for standard builtin asp calendar?)
- It use an array of `View` object to load each month in clientside.

does anyone knows whats going on in the standard builtin calendar of `Asp.Net` so that it can shows calendar such nice?
could you guys please get me to the right direction? i don't know what other information should i provide. so tell me if it's needed.

Comment: Try other datetime pickers: http://www.dotnettips.info/newsarchive/details/1122

Comment: @VahidN i don't wanna use them because 1- it should be DevExpress theme compatible and 2- devexpress `DateEdit` component has a very unique time picker carrying with this control and i don't wanna miss that.